# CocoaPods adds duplicate project to xcworkspace

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcode6

My workspace structure is the following:
-ProjectA
--ProjectB
--ProjectC
-Pods

I run the 'pod update' and what I get is
-ProjectA
--ProjectB
--ProjectC
-Pods
-ProjectB <- this should not be here!

My Podfile is:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!
workspace 'ProjectA'

target :ProjectA do
    pod "AFNetworking", "~> 2.0"
    pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'
    pod 'SDWebImage'
    pod 'FXBlurView'
    pod 'RESideMenu'
    pod 'RBStoryboardLink'
end

target :ProjectBTests do
    xcodeproj 'Libraries/ProjectB/ProjectB'
    pod 'Expecta'
    pod 'Specta'
    pod 'OCMock'
end
```

So is it possible to do anything with such behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: just out of curiosity: why xcodeproj 'Libraries/ProjectB/ProjectB'? 2 times ProjectB?

Comment: Please answer the question above

Comment: Thats OK. xcodeproj 'ProjectB/ProjectB' is assumed as ProjectB/ProjectB.xcodeproj

Comment: Sorry, I somehow missed the question. But @bllakjakk is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1):

Please register it as a bug in coocoapods.
The generated xcworkspace file is incorrect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workspace
   version = "1.0">
   <FileRef
      location = "group:ProjectA.xcodeproj">
   </FileRef>
   <FileRef
      location = "group:Pods/Pods.xcodeproj">
   </FileRef>
   <FileRef
      location = "group:ProjectA/ProjectB/ProjectB.xcodeproj">
   </FileRef>
</Workspace>
```

Comment: I reported the bug: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2413, but it was closed.

Comment: Since I already verified by creating same structure as yours. So the approach is correct. But CocoaPods doesn't support that yet. For the time being I would suggest you to update the xcworkspace file by deleting the duplicate relationship. It will work just fine as the pods are already associated with the nested project. Enjoy.

Comment: @bllakjakk Do you have any idea how to do the xcworkspace updating automatically (e.g. after each pod install/update)?

Comment: 2017, any update on this? encountering the same issue

Comment: The same issue appears for me

Comment: Still happening on Jan/12/2019 :(

Answer (score 1):

Replaced this line in `lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator.rb` `#create_workspace`:

```
new_file_references = file_references - workspace.file_references
```

with this code instead:

```
new_file_references = file_references - workspace.file_references    
absolute_paths = workspace.file_references.map { |fr| fr.absolute_path(workspace_path) }
new_file_references = new_file_references.select { |fr| absolute_paths.include? fr.absolute_path(workspace_path)  }
```

Basically use the absolute path to filter the items that have been added to the workspace already.

Answer (score -1):

***TLDR**: This is a user's workspace bug. To fix the issue just open your workspace's `contents.xcworkspacedata` in a text editor and simplify all relative paths. E.g. `OMGNotExistingDirectory/../FirstLibrary/FirstLibrary.xcodeproj` should now look like `FirstLibrary/FirstLibrary.xcodeproj`*

So, sometimes while rearranging your projects in a workspace your `contents.xcworkspacedata` may end up like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workspace
   version = "1.0">
   <FileRef
      location = "group:App/App.xcodeproj">
   </FileRef>
   <FileRef
      location = "group:OMGNotExistingDirectory/../FirstLibrary/FirstLibrary.xcodeproj">
   </FileRef>
   <FileRef
      location = "group:SecondLibrary/SecondLibrary.xcodeproj">
   </FileRef>
   <FileRef
      location = "group:ThirdLibrary/ThirdLibrary.xcodeproj">
   </FileRef>
</Workspace>
```

See that `OMGNotExistingDirectory/../FirstLibrary/FirstLibrary.xcodeproj` ? Yes, that's the problem. Even if the folder in the path does not exist anymore the `/..` part of the path allows XCode to ignore it and work without problems.

Now we run `pod install`. The problem here is when CocoaPods reassembles the workspace it compares **relative** paths instead of **absolute** to avoid duplicates. And, of course, `FirstLibrary/FirstLibrary.xcodeproj` is not `OMGNotExistingDirectory/../FirstLibrary/FirstLibrary.xcodeproj` even though they are pointing to the same file.

So to fix the issue you have to simplify the relative paths in your workspace by removing redundant parts in them.

Thanks to [kezi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1484378/kezi)'s answer for giving a clue of where the issue is.

Comment: So uhm...If I understand correctly, after `pod install`, it added this into my xcworkspacedata `location = "group:../submodules/MySDK/MySDK.xcodeproj">`, I just go and delete the `../submodules/`? But if I ran `pod install` again it still show, would there be duplicate error when building like before?

Comment: @Tj3n Not really. In your case the group is not located in the same directory as your workspace. E.g. your project folder contains `Main Project` and `submodules` directories. And if the `Main Project` folder contains your workspace and `submodules/MySDK` contains `MySDK.xcodeproj`, then in  order to reference the `MySDK.xcodeproj` your workspace has to use these `../` path parts. Basically it means "Go into the parent directory". And if your path does not have anything before the `../` part then there is nothing to simplify :(

Comment: I take it that this won't help it for my case? Even in pod 1.8 this issue still there, I was looking for a way to remove the duplicated one via post install hook but can't find any code for it..

Comment: @Tj3n How do your original and duplicated locations looks like?

Comment: My setup look the same as the OP, after `pod install` in the `workspacedata` it show MyApp + pod + MySDK mentioned above, if I remove that MySDK group, the `MySDK` stay fine inside the MyApp project and the duplicate went away, original MySDK don't seems to got displayed in the `workspacedata`